# What is the Wand of Paralysis' Saving Throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, saving-throw

The magical item the Wand of Paralysis is extremely unclear as to how a person is to remove the effects of paralysis that the wand instills. In the DMG, page 211, it states "Make a ranged attack roll against that creature using your spell attack bonus. On a hit, the target is paralyzed for 1 minute. At the end of each of the target's turns, it can repeat the saving throw, ending the effect on itself on a success." The DMG fails to mention, however, what type of saving throw it calls for (whether it's dexterity, constitution, etc.), or how to determine the DC (whether it is your spell save DC or a predetermined DC for the item).

What is the saving throw to end the paralysis, and how do I determine the DC?

Comment: Related/Duplicate? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60456/what-is-the-spell-attack-bonus-and-spell-save-dc-of-a-thief-using-the-use-magic/72411#72411

Answer (score 18):

This was addressed in the [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf)

> Wand of Paralysis (p. 211). The third and fourth sentences now read as
>   follows: “The target must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw
>   or be paralyzed for 1 minute.”

The text above replaces the below...

> Make a ranged attack roll against that creature using your spell
>   attack bonus. On a hit, the target is paralyzed for 1 minute.

Comment: @RavenPoe If this answer satisfies your issue feel free to accept it.