# Which originally published items would meaningfully benefit a 'Thief' Rogue that had Use Magic Device?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, rogue, thief

This class feature seemed to me to be dead-on-arrival when published.

It's unclear exactly which items originally presented in the DMG that this feature was intended to work with.

- Exactly which items in the DMG are made usable by a level 13
  Thief when granted the Use Magic Device class feature?
- Of those items, which of them are meaningfully useful to a creature that doesn't otherwise meet those requirements?

  (For example: Pearl of Power does nothing for a Thief even if they can ignore the class requirement of "spellcaster", so it is not meaningfully useful.)

Extending this question to all published works would be too vast of a question, but limiting it to originally published materials should be a reasonable task.

Comment: Apologies for the weird grammar. This question was poorly-proofread before I submitted it and it's been a long day.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following items from the DMG are included and useful:

- Dwarven Thrower
- Holy Avengers
- Instruments of the Bards
- Moonblades, but only if you are neutral good
- Prayer Beads
- Robe of the Archmagi (but only if its alignment matches) (15+Dex AC and bonuses against spells)
- Rod of Resurrection
- 11 different kinds of staves
- Tome of the Stilled Tongue (bonus action cast one spell per day)
- 7* kinds of wands, but you could already use those if you were a spellcaster e.g. a high-elf rogue
- Whelm
- [All spell scrolls](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/11/07/does-the-thief-rogues-use-magic-device-cover-the-use-of-spell-scrolls/)

Note that the PHB has no magic items.

Mostly these magic items give you potent spellcasting abilities, but some of them (the robe of the archmagi and the staff of power) also raise your AC.  A rogue with a +3 shield and staff of power and appropriate Robe could have an AC as high as 30.

*Moonblade*s are a special case where this feature gives a thief access to something truly uniquely powerful, though since that's a racial rather than class restriction it's not like you couldn't have had one anyways just by playing an elf or half-elf.

---

- this assumes you go with the RAI rather than RAW on [this answer here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102404/33569), i.e. 'requires attunement by a spellcaster' counts as a class restriction bypassed by this feature instead of not.

Comment: Related: [(How) Can a Rogue use Use Magic Device to cast spells from Scrolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89098/33569), [What is the spell attack bonus and spell save DC of a Thief using the Use Magic Device feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60456/33569), [Does the “use magic device” feature of the thief subclass allow you to attune to items requiring you to be a spellcaster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102404/33569)

Comment: More related things: "[Does an Artificer's Magic Item Savant and a Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device allow them to benefit from a Holy Avenger's 30-foot aura?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163203)" and "[Does an Artificer's Magic Item Savant and a multiclassed Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device allow them to benefit from a Rod of the Pact Keeper?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163204)"

Comment: The killer-feature of that list are IMO spell scrolls and wands, because those unlock a whole range of spellcasting abilities to the rogue and are usually not difficult to come by (although the availability in your specific campaign might vary).

Comment: Staves are the real kicker, imo,  but wands are good, too.

Comment: The only problem with wands and staffs is that you will need to receive them as hand-me-downs, since most spellcasters will probably get first dibs.

Comment: [Jeremy Crawford recently responded to a tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1227661727761719296) to confirm that the artificer's Magic Item Savant allows artificers to ignore the attunement requirement on magic items that can only be attuned to by a creature with a certain dragonmark, since dragonmarks are mechanically subraces. (It looks like the same is true of the [Thief rogue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Thief)'s Use Magic Item feature.) Doesn't meet OP's criteria of being in the DMG, but interesting to note.

Comment: The issue of Use Magic Device and *spell scrolls* is now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=6): "**Does the Thief ’s Use Magic Device feature allow them to use spell scrolls?** Yes. The intent is that a Thief can use spell scrolls with Use Magic Device." You may want to update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Axoren Assuming the party has any spellcasters capable of using the item. Eg in a party of a wizard, fighter, cleric and thief rogue, the Staff of the Woodlands is only usable by the rogue.